# Cannot set private nic speed to 10Gbps

Tags: api, networking, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, nic

When using slcli to modify the port speed of the private nic to 10gbps, I get the following error:

```
slcli hardware edit --private-speed 10000 123456  
SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): Speed cannot be null and must be 0 (Disconnect), 10, 100, or 1000.
```

I am able to change the port speed via the UI and by opening a ticket, so am wondering if there is an issue with the API or an account setting that must be enabled.  We use bonded NICs, so we actually need to set the speed to 20000.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue but I could not. I am capable to change the speed to 10000 whith no problem. I only get the error when the private nic does not have that speed available. I am not sure what is your NIC configuration but this is mine:

[image]

As you can see the "Max Speed" for my configuration is 10000 Mbps, so using the slcli comand I can change the "Speed" whithout any problem, in case that the "Max Speed" is under 10000 Mbps I got the same error as you, in order to head off that error I need to "Modify the Max Speed" to another configuration that allows more speed, but in order to make the same using the API you need to upgrade your server using the placeOrder method.

Another thing is that you cannot set any value that you want in the speed property, it depends of your NIC setup, but generally speaking the only valid values are: 0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000; As you can see you cannot set the speed to 20000.

Regards

Comment: So first we need to use the placeOrder method to set the max speed to 10Gbps on each interface, then make another API call to modify the speed?  That seems cumbersome.  Does the API not support bonded interfaces?

Comment: yes that is the proccess, "Speed" and "Max Speed" are two differents things for the API. Softlayer did it like that if you need help about how to change the "Max Speed" via API let me know